# Using a NSDateFormatter for an Editable textfield in a view-based NSTableview

Tags: cocoa, date, nsdateformatter, nstableview

I'm struggling with an OS X app that uses a view-based NSTableview to display various objects managed by Core Data. Most of this is managed in interface builder, so here's a description of what's set up there:  I have a single column that lists each entry by date. The column's view only contains a single NSTextField, and I dragged a NSDateFormatter onto that textfield's cell.  The content of the NSTableview is bound to an NSArrayController that holds the Entities I'm listing, each of which has an attribute of "date". The value of the NSTextField is bound to "Table Cell View" and objectvalue.date.

So all this works pretty well to display a list of the dates, and the NSDateFormatter set up in interface builder lets me set how the dates are displayed (Medium style, etc). However, I need these date fields to be editable, and whenever I try to edit one of the text fields containing the dates, I get an alert that the new value is not valid.

How can I set it up, either in IB or in code, so that a user can edit these dates correctly? I'd really like for entry to be pretty lenient here, and accept natural language strings if possible.

Do I need to subclass the NSTextfield to validate differently? Or is this a problem with the NSDateFormatter?

(BTW, I'm coding in swift, if you have code tips for this problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I never really figured out how to approach this like I was trying to originally, but since this question has been out and unanswered for a while, I've decided to post how I handled the situation, even though it's more of a work around.

I decided to abandon editing and validating the textfields for dates. Now they only display the date for each entry. For the editing functionality, I changed the target for the tableview's "doubleAction:" to display a popup containing a graphical NSDatePicker, which has its value bound to the date of the object selected in the tableview. Then, when the user selects a different date, it changes the value and dismisses the popup.

I think that the user interaction works just as well, or perhaps even better, than what I imagined when I originally posted this question.